# Debugging side-loaded add-in running in Word

Tags: javascript, office365, office-js, word-addins

I've been debugging my addins using Word online through the Chrome developer tools. However I would like to start debugging in the Office 365 client and not its web counterpart. I am able to load my add-in manifest and open the add-in task pane. Everything runs fine, but I cannot seem to open a debugger/output/whatever.

I have tried using the windows F12 tool and attaching it, but it never shows any processes running even though Word and the add-in are running.

Is there something I need to configure for this to work properly? Or is there some other way to debug?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this article to find out which browser is being used: [Browsers used by Office Web Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins). If Edge is being used, then the add-in will not appear in the F12 tool. You have to use the [Edge Development Tools Preview](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/microsoft-edge-devtools-preview/9mzbfrmz0mnj?activetab=pivot:overviewtab).

Comment: Oh! It's using Edge indeed, and using those developer tools I was able to attach it to the add-in! Thanks a bunch!